# Pick a cup from a table

Tags: octomap, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.
I have been trying to pick up a cup from a table.
if the cup is at the edge of the table it works pretty well.
the thing is what I am doing is adding a "surface" under the detected cup (just a rectangle) and then it avoid the collision nicely.
But when the cup is not at the end of the table, the measures of the "surface" is hard coded, hence it doesn't avoid the table and the arm collide with it.
I have been looking for answers but I didn't find any, Is there a way to add the table to the collision avoiding with a not hard coded surface? using point-cloud or something? I have also seen something regarding Octomap if so is there any good tutorial for that? I couldn't understand the one on Move it tutorials.
My robot has kinect camera with point cloud2 and depth.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340903/pick-a-cup-from-a-table/) by [omer91](https://answers.ros.org/users/33188/omer91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2020-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add the point cloud to the MoveIt collision scene as you're probably already doing with the hardcoded surface as explained in the [perception tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/perception_pipeline/perception_pipeline_tutorial.html). That tutorial is pretty well explained especially if you follow along with the previous tutorials in that series. You don't need to understand `octomap` beyond that it essentially is a compact representation for point clouds. I would recommend trying the setup with the panda arm used in the tutorial in simulation first and then setting up your own system once you get it working.

You would have to add a pretty accurate transformation to the `tf` tree from the base of your arm to the camera center. It would give you a collision scene that includes everything the camera can see, not necessarily the entire table.

---

Originally posted by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) with karma: 464 on 2020-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1